# Application Error when attempting to deploy Node.js/Express/mongodb application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I have seen very similar posts, that however did not help me to find a solution to my problems.

can any one please help why i am getting this error on heroku and hope to rectify it??

here is full logs for heroku

```
2015-12-26T16:21:43.901904+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-12-26T16:21:43.902144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! exp2014@0.0.0 start: `node
 ./bin/www`
2015-12-26T16:21:43.902363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-12-26T16:21:43.902631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-12-26T16:21:43.902856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the exp2014@0.0.
0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2015-12-26T16:21:43.903083+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the lat
est version of node.js and npm installed.
2015-12-26T16:21:43.903306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most li
kely a problem with the exp2014 package,
2015-12-26T16:21:43.903518+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873454+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.903748+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.903956+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873459+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modu
les/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873460+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function()
 { throw err; })
2015-12-26T16:21:43.904170+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via
:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873461+00:00 app[web.1]:
   ^
2015-12-26T16:21:43.904382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls exp2014
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873466+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoExcepti
on (util.js:856:11)
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873465+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0
.1:27017
2015-12-26T16:21:43.904614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873466+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPo
rt (util.js:879:20)
2015-12-26T16:21:43.873468+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect
[as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
2015-12-26T16:21:43.908441+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.892982+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.908760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2015-12-26T16:21:43.908960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-12-26T16:21:44.851147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-12-26T16:21:43.881393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connect
ion closed without response" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-864
0.herokuapp.com request_id=ec301344-6363-4952-84c8-6c61ff07ae95 fwd="182.93.90.5
1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=54ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-12-26T16:21:45.967001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2015-12-26T16:21:48.569954+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:48.570008+00:00 app[web.1]: > exp2014@0.0.0 start /app
2015-12-26T16:21:48.570010+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-12-26T16:21:48.570010+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:49.077984+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is running at 17445
2015-12-26T16:21:49.591851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2015-12-26T16:21:51.965557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=f7cb65ec-626c-42b0-ad17-47e86df64
902 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service=34ms status=304 bytes=2
37
2015-12-26T16:21:51.941923+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 304 6.929 ms - -
2015-12-26T16:21:52.433960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/css/grid12.css" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=00e8dd9f-ed5
8-485c-bc4d-ec06d4a9c339 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms
status=200 bytes=15580
2015-12-26T16:21:52.476019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/js/libs/angular.min.js" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=800a
5064-a116-46a0-b423-ac75b8a5ad75 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms servi
ce=3ms status=304 bytes=239
2015-12-26T16:21:52.437724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/css/text.css" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=dc701bcc-436c-
474f-970f-fe89012aa88b fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms sta
tus=200 bytes=1351
2015-12-26T16:21:52.438400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/css/gallerycss-csstable-min.css" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=e1b276c7-cad5-497b-843b-449306c47dee fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=
2ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=1284
2015-12-26T16:21:52.442105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/css/ionic.min.css" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=71dbc93e-
6e98-478a-a5b3-881799bcffa2 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4m
s status=304 bytes=239
2015-12-26T16:21:52.435661+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/css/gallerycss-csstable
-min.css 200 5.749 ms - 997
2015-12-26T16:21:52.439825+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/css/ionic.min.css 304 1
.024 ms - -
2015-12-26T16:21:52.426003+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/css/grid12.css 200 8.21
8 ms - 15290
2015-12-26T16:21:52.436386+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/css/text.css 200 5.346
ms - 1063
2015-12-26T16:21:52.450517+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/js/libs/angular.min.js
304 0.537 ms - -
2015-12-26T16:21:52.915044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/publi
c/js/app.js" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=4c97b7a8-cec2-49f
6-a498-5acc081e9efe fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms statu
s=200 bytes=902
2015-12-26T16:21:52.895728+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /public/js/app.js 200 1.337 ms
- 616
2015-12-26T16:21:53.551615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connect
ion closed without response" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-864
0.herokuapp.com request_id=b78f628c-34c2-4419-83f7-30b00235f42d fwd="182.93.90.5
1" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=39ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540393+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540403+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modu
les/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540405+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function()
 { throw err; })
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540406+00:00 app[web.1]:
   ^
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540412+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0
.1:27017
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoExcepti
on (util.js:856:11)
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect
[as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
2015-12-26T16:21:53.540413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPo
rt (util.js:879:20)
2015-12-26T16:21:53.560253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
2015-12-26T16:21:53.562639+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-12-26T16:21:53.555441+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.560801+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-12-26T16:21:53.561174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.1.1
2015-12-26T16:21:53.562127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
2015-12-26T16:21:53.562977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! exp2014@0.0.0 start: `node
 ./bin/www`
2015-12-26T16:21:53.563279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-12-26T16:21:53.563594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-12-26T16:21:53.563839+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the exp2014@0.0.
0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2015-12-26T16:21:53.564155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the lat
est version of node.js and npm installed.
2015-12-26T16:21:53.564392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most li
kely a problem with the exp2014 package,
2015-12-26T16:21:53.564615+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-12-26T16:21:53.565077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-12-26T16:21:53.564863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.565397+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via
:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.565595+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls exp2014
2015-12-26T16:21:53.565807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2015-12-26T16:21:53.570509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.570244+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-26T16:21:53.570664+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-12-26T16:21:54.276984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2015-12-26T16:21:54.254278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-12-26T16:21:55.767214+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=51a4
6763-03db-4a36-8ac3-dd39c308c4e9 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= service= stat
us=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:21:44.867263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2015-12-26T16:21:44.868220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-12-26T16:22:31.800808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=6e198f08-2bc0-42f2-99b1-279318b0d30f fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:31.812528+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=583d5d1b-efdc-40bd-8b28-990db58a7720 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:32.494105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=1d4915bc-42c3-4a59-aa64-df3967f21ae5 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:33.481676+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=4740ebf2-5b3a-403c-94a8-564ac23753a8 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:33.404966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=839286d4-4e1a-49e8-b647-2b3d0e636ffc fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:34.196401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=61168a33-4ada-4af8-9e70-6f63f51dcda9 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:37.622802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=e4141aea-de6b-4b91-9b8a-419f2efab392 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:38.806705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=e3fd097d-e723-4961-8349-4309e2c98a98 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:38.794005+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=448abba1-cfa5-479c-9296-670939de4f95 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:38.932653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=b706f421-538a-4e85-84e9-617369cd3dfa fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:39.158882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=4bf0fa6f-1913-486f-ae9e-e1ab5e7b1152 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:39.820833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=f4e285d8-3084-49d0-af46-9490309fc0c3 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:43.023735+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=4b075f15-bed1-4ef5-a6df-a9979c6693bf fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:43.027365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=ff5244d7-3438-48c7-8628-b770229b5a4e fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:44.323182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=POST path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=2d96f080-943c-486d-a2db-d8ebb64789e1 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:45.014054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/userList" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request
_id=5adb320a-b344-4388-9015-184ab1533085 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:22:59.501583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=beeb
95f3-ac20-414c-b32b-d35647a5ec24 fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= service= stat
us=503 bytes=
2015-12-26T16:23:03.136290+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-shore-8640.herokuapp.com request_id=15ba
f68c-bb75-4b21-8655-da7139ed15fe fwd="182.93.90.51" dyno= connect= service= stat
us=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Your app failed to connect to mongodb and the address 127.0.0.1:27017 doesn't look correct to me. Is your mongodb hosted on heroku or somewhere else?

Comment: not yet. but i am still working on it. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Moda i found mongolab ad ons on heroku for my database connection now, so i also create db on mongolab,but still got above logs, Did i something missed??

Comment: you have configured your app to connect to mongodb at 127.0.0.1:27017 so change that to your mongolab